# jQuery select element after async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with selecting element after generating by async callback function.
How to do that?

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function1(function2);
//here i want to select generated element by id $('#select-id')
});

function function1(callback) {
    $.getJSON('./ajax/results_get.php', function(data) {
console.log("function1");
        callback();
    });
}

function function2() {
console.log("function2");
}
```

EDIT:
Now i used callback, but i don't know how to make visible object created within function3 to the click button event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function1(function() {
        function2(function() {
            function3(function(){
var foo = $('#element');
            });
        });
    });

                $('#savebtn').click(function(){
//how to use assigned foo here?

                });
});
```

Comment: If select-id element is added dynamically then you need to do so in one of the callback functions

Comment: select-id element is updated dynamically. It's in DOM tree before the function call. I need this selector to be visible in the `$(document).ready`

Comment: Current code updated in main post

Comment: Can't you use `$('#element')`directly? For what I understand, there is no need to define `var foo = $('#element')` to use it elsewhere in the code (or I missed something).